# WPF ValidationRule for StartDate and EndDate

Tags: wpf, validationrules, validationrule

In my WPF application I need to compare two textbox fields (say startDate and enddate) -- I am not using DatePicker-- using Validation-Rules.

Is there any workarounds to approach this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kyle: in my form I have two text boxes that needs to be validated against each other. Forexample user provides 2012-12-25 as StartDate and 2011-01-12 as EndDate. Logically its not true. So I need to write a validationRule. But the point is I do not know how to pass two parameters to may Validate function in this ValidationRule!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create 2 custom validationrules on for the StartDate who have date property that binds from the EndDate and the same for the EndDate which point to the startdate. Also you will be abble to validate and compare in each validationrule you implemented.

---

I hope I was very expressive. I have no time provide a code. If I do one for my Apps I will paste the code here !

Comment: You don't need the disclaimer, and though it is an "answer" you could have likely left this as a comment, assuming you have enough rep to do so.